# Loss in data after conversion from .shp to .tif using QGIS

Tags: shapefile, convert, geotiff-tiff

I have some .shp data, which include points with values. After converting it into .tif, using QGIS, I have some loses in data.

In .shp file sum of field was about 141418146 and in .tif image sum is about 139544448. How can I save my data after conversion? 

 Any suggestions are acceptable.

Comment: It sounds like you've got two or more points on the same cell, the cell can have only one value so the others are 'missing'. What process did you use to rasterize your points? What is your cell size and how does that compare with the spread of your data? If you add a field or use an existing but unneeded field and calc 1 into it, when you rasterize with the same process do you get the same sum as the number of points?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me to understand my problem. How can I convert these points without "missing"?

Comment: I used Raster - Conversion - Rasterize process. My cell size is 1km x 1km. I compared results using Python gdal module. When I add new field and calc it into 1 and the rasterize - I get 75 instead of 79

Comment: You cannot convert the points to raster without this happening. The best you can do is make your cell size smaller and *hope* that in no instance two or more points are on the same raster cell.